# Show that any plane whose normal lies on cone $(b+c)x^2+(c+a)y^2+(a+b)z^2=0$ cuts the surface $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=1$ is rectangular hyperbola

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, 3d, solid-geometry, convex-cone

Show that any plane whose normal lies on cone $(b+c)x^2+(c+a)y^2+(a+b)z^2=0$ cuts the surface $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=1$ is rectangular hyperbola

My attempt:
let $\frac {x}{l} = \frac {y}{m} = \frac {z}{n}$ be normal of plane $lx+my+nz = 0$. Now the normal is generator of given cone. So we get condition $(b+c)l^2+(c+a)m^2+(a+b)n^2=0$ --->(1)

THe given plane cuts the conicoid $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=1$.

### The intersecting conic :

Eliminating z between plane equation and conicoid equation

$z = \frac{-lx-my}{n} $ Subsittuting this in conicoid equation we get,

$ax^2+by^2+c\frac{(-lx-my)^2}{n^2} =1 $ --->(2)

This represents rectangular hyperbola if

coefficient of $x^2$ + coefficient of $y^2$ = 0

$(2)$ implies

$a+b+c\frac{l^2}{n^2}+c\frac{m^2}{n^2} =0 \\ \fbox {$n^2(a+b) + c(l^2+m^2) = 0$}$ for conic to be rectangular hyperbola

If i eliminate x, i get $\fbox {$l^2(b+c)+a(m^2+n^2)=0$}$  for conic to be rectangular hyperbola

If i eliminate y, i get $\fbox {$m^2(c+a)+b(n^2+l^2)=0$}$  for conic to be rectangular hyperbola

But what i have is  equation (1) with me for conic to be rectangular hyperbola

How to proceed further?

Comment: Eliminating $z$ from the equations gives you the equation of a *projection* of the intersection curve onto the $x$-$y$ plane, not the curve itself.

Comment: @amd yes that is what i got - projections on xy, yz, zx ... how to go ahead? pls guide

Comment: @amd projection on XY plane would be the result of taking $z=0$, not eliminating $z$. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we will make some required transformations to assure that the formula $(b+c)x^2+(c+a)y^2+(a+b)z^2=0\;$ represents a real cone.

A real cone with circular base over the $x \times y$ plane and vertice at the origin should be represented as

$$
K\to m x^2+n y^2+p z^2 = 0
$$

with $m = n$ and $m > 0, n > 0, p < 0$

so we will choose $a,b,c$ such that

$$
b+c=m\\
a+c=n\\
a+b=p
$$

in this representation a line $L$

$$
L\to P = \rho\vec v \to
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
x = \rho \alpha\\
y = \rho \beta\\
z = \rho \gamma
\end{array}
\right.\;\;\;\; P = (x,y,z)
$$

is such that $L \in K$ when

$$
m\alpha^2+n\beta^2+p\gamma^2=0
$$

Now with the help of $\vec v$ and $\vec w = (m\alpha,n\beta,p\gamma)$ Here $\left < \vec v, \vec w\right> = 0$, we can build a plane $\Pi$

$$
\Pi\to P = \lambda \vec w + \mu \left(\vec v \times \vec w\right)
$$

as required. Given now the surface

$$
S\to ax^2+by^2+cy^2-1=0\equiv \frac{1}{2} x^2 (-m+n+p)+\frac{1}{2} y^2 (m-n+p)+\frac{1}{2} z^2 (m+n-p)-1 = 0
$$

the intersection $S\cap \Pi$ is obtained

$$
\left(S\circ\Pi\right)(\lambda,\mu) = \frac{1}{2} \left(-4 (m-n-p) (\alpha  \lambda  m+\beta  \gamma  \mu  (n-p))^2+4 (m+n-p) (\alpha  \beta  \mu  (m-n)+\gamma  \lambda  p)^2+4 (m-n+p)
   (\alpha  \gamma  \mu  (p-m)+\beta  \lambda  n)^2-2\right)= 0
$$

but we can introduce a slight normalization to simplify the representation by considering

$$
m\alpha^2+n\beta^2+p\gamma^2=0\\
\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2 = 1\\
\beta = \beta_0 = 0\\
m = n\\
$$

and thus we have the intersection curve on $\Pi$ as

$$
2np^2\lambda^2-2np^2\mu^2-1=0
$$

which is a rectangular hyperbola.

Comment: i did not understand following -- (1) Any 2 points on line will be $(m \alpha , n\beta, p \ gamma), ( \alpha , \beta, \ gamma)$ these form 2 points on normal to plane. But these apparantly seem perpendicular. How is that possible? (2)I did not understand how did u write Surface equaiton and plane equation. Plane equatin = $\vec n/(\vec r- \vec r_0)=0$ . Here $\vec v \cross \vec w $ gives line that is in given plane. Then i did not understand meaning of $w+v \cross w$

Comment: @Magneto $L \in K \Rightarrow \rho^2(m\alpha^2+n\beta^2+p\gamma^2)=0$ Here $\vec v = (\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ has the line direction and $\vec w =(m\alpha,n\beta,p\gamma)$ is orthogonal to $\vec v$ then the plane $\Pi\to P = \lambda \vec v + \mu \vec v \times\vec w$ by construction, is the required plane.

Comment: @Magneto I didn't  understand the formula you wrote $\vec n /(\vec r-\vec r_0)$ ??

Comment: i understood the proof now. Thank you. Too good. But can u tell me where i went wrong? i could not find out. Pls see it once. It helps in rectifying my mistake

Comment: @Magneto I think that  the real problem is to establish the conditions in $a,b,c$ for $(b+c)x^2+(c+a)y^2+(a+b)z^2=0$ to be representing a real cone. Try your way including before those conditions.

Comment: Ok will try ... Tq for ur detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution,

Let $/$=$/$=$/$ be normal of plane ++=0. Now the normal is generator of given cone. So we get condition $(+)^2$+$(+)^2$+$(+)^2$=0 -----------(eq. 1)

Thus, our required plane is lx+my+nx=p whose normal is $/$=$/$=$/$

We now show that it's intersection with conicoid: $^2$+$^2$+$^2$=1 generates rectangular hyperbola, i.e. the asymptotes are mutually perpendicular.

Consider the asymptotes in the plane (lx+my+nx=p) as
$(-x_0)/p$=$(-y_0)/q$=$(-z_0)/r$, having DCs <p,q,r> thus we should show that $p_1p_2$+$q_1q_2$+$r_1r_2$=0 then it will be a rectangular hyperbola.

Now, since the line (asymptote) with DCs <p,q,r> lie in plane lx+my+nz=p,
thus lp+mq+nr=0 --------(eq.2)

For the line $(-x_0)/p$=$(-y_0)/q$=$(-z_0)/r$ = k(say), we have x=kp+$x_0$ ; y=qk+$y_0$ ; z=rk+$z_0$ and we put this in conicoid equation $^2$+$^2$+$^2$=1

we will get a quadratic in $k^2$, here we can put the coefficient of $k^2$ equal to zero, since the solution will be at infinity (for asymptote).
Hence, we get another equation:
$ap^2$+$bq^2$+$cr^2$=0 ---------(eq.3)

from equation 2 and equation 3, putting $p_1p_2$+$q_1q_2$+$r_1r_2$=0 (here, we just need to show sum of product of roots is zero)
we will get our equation 1  i.e. $(+)^2$+$(+)^2$+$(+)^2$=0

Q.E.D.